# 404 error on all pages except first page when setting context path in context.xml

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, path, http-status-code-404

I am experimenting with the path attribute in the context.xml file of my Spring MVC app.  Currently i have it set to `path=""` and everything works perfectly but it results in the URL only showing `localhost:8080/`.

What i would like to accomplish is to change the context path to the name of my project so that the URL actually reflects the application name and doesn't just point to the root (localhost:8080/nameOfProject).  I changed the context.xml to contain the following :

```
<Context path="/MDHIS_WebClient"/>
```

With this change, only the login page works and any other page gives a

> 404 error

I am using Maven for the build and the project is fully annotation-driven, there is no `web.xml`.

***EDIT***

Here is my ApplicationInitializer class :

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer 
{
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException 
{
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(container);

    ContextLoaderListener contextLoaderListener = new ContextLoaderListener(ctx);
    ctx.getServletContext().addListener(contextLoaderListener);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");

    ctx.refresh();

    if (ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("dbReset").compareTo("ON") == 0)
    {
        ((DatabaseLoader)ctx.getBean("databaseLoader")).loadData();
    }

    LineCounter.countLines();
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) 
{
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
}
```

How can i have it search for the pages under the correct application names for the subsequent pages?  Thanks

***ANOTHER EDIT***

I'm starting to think that this change needs to be reflected in my application's links and controllers as well for everything to work right.  This is how my menu currently calls my communication status page :

```
<a href="/communications/list">Communications</a>
```

This is how the controller is set to intercept the call :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/communications")
public class CommunicationController 
{
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionService connectionService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewInterfaceCommunications(ModelMap model) 
    {
        List<Connection> connections = connectionService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("connections", connections);

        return "interfaceConnections";
    }
}
```

How are you guys managing to populate the name of your web app in your URLs?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not using Spring Security, i will add my ApplicationInitializer class

Comment: Sorry, a typo. How are you plugging in spring mvc?

Comment: added the init class

Comment: are you using springboot?

Comment: I am not using Spring Boot, the code i have added is the main code that intializes Spring MVC

Comment: Have you tried ending the context path with a `/`?

Comment: This sadly doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to this, declaring a bean such as the one below in any config class fixes the problem and adds the context to the URL :

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() 
{
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/LEM2");
}
```

Note these classes are part of Spring Boot so you need to use it for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly.

Here is what you could try.

1. Clean and Re-build the project.
2. go to "apache folder/work/Catalina/localhost" and delete every thing then re-deploy the project.

hope that help.

Comment: None of this works unfortunately, i'm still stuck with only the first page working.  Whatever i do next tries to search for the URL of the pages with the application name missing.  Everything works perfectly when context.xml only contains <Context path=""/>, albeit with the application name missing from the URL everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this block to your config code? I am assuming other pages in your app are .html

```
@Bean
      public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/yourPathToOtherPages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
      return resolver;
    }
```

Comment: I already have a bean of this type configured :

@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() 
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        return viewResolver;
    }